# Android: Having trouble implementing a shared ViewModel to push data from the viewmodel to fragments using the activity scope

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewmodel

I have been stuck on this issue for a while. I am running a server on a viewmodel and using its variables to update fragments with new data from new server messages. I am following the method used in the following link to utilize one viewmodel between fragments: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

This is my code in the fragment onCreateView() method where I try to access a viewModel with the Activity's scope:

```
    ServerDataViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(ServerDataViewModel.class);
```

I get the following error:

```
    error: no suitable constructor found for ViewModelProvider(Activity)
    constructor ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner,Factory) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStore,Factory) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

I've tried creating the viewmodel in the activity first with issues as well, it seems I need to include a viewmodel factory, I'm not sure how to access that from a fragment. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If switching to Kotlin is a possibility. With kotlins KTX library it becomes super convenient to [instantiate an activity scoped view model](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment)

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your ViewModel class?

Comment: The viewModel class is about 200 lines so It wouldnt be very practical to post. But basically the viewmodel has a thread that constantly listens for new data on the servefr and updates its global variables to be accessed with gettter methods.

Comment: I have no experience with kotlin and would rather find a work around in java if possible. However I may switch if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Are there arguments defined in your ViewModel's constructor? If you can post the ViewModel's constructor, that would give a clearer picture.

Comment: I have no constructor defined for my viewmodel.

Comment: Ok. I think that should be fine if you're extending ViewModel. Are you extending AndroidViewModel?

Comment: I have: public class ServerDataViewModel extends ViewModel I am extending ViewModel. Still having the issue

Comment: With the given information, I'm not seeing where the problem could be. The last thing I can suggest is to try creating an empty constructor but that's honestly a shot in the dark.